# copying a formula from another sheet and pasting it to master sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This might be too easy for many but i need an help.

I have following formula in Sheet1 which takes the value from Sheet2 M3 Cell

```
='Sheet2'!M3
```

M3 cell in Sheet2 has a formula inside which is following:

```
 =INT(NETWORKDAYS(K3;L3)/5)+1
```

I want to paste the formula inside M3 to my formula in Sheet1 but when i do this as following i get an error.

```
  ='Sheet2'!INT(NETWORKDAYS(K3;L3)/5)+1
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here and how i can paste this formula correctly so it works?

Answer (score 1):

Your question was a bit confuse, but:

1. Do you want the `NETWORKDAYS` formula to get data from Sheet1 itself?

If yes, just erase the `'Sheet2'!` part of your formula.
 2. Do you want the `NETWORKDAYS` formula to get data from Sheet2?
If yes, this is the final formula:

```
=INT(NETWORKDAYS('Sheet2'!K3;'Sheet2'!L3)/5)+1
```

The problem is that you should use Sheet reference (`'Sheet2'!`) before cells, not before formula, so that Excel knows where it should get the data.

Answer (score 0):

say we have:

*Sheet1* cell **A1** contains the formula:`='Sheet2'!M3`
*Sheet2* cell **M3** contains the formula:`=INT(NETWORKDAYS(K3;L3)/5)+1`
Select the **A1** cell and run this short macro:

```
Sub FormulaGrabber()
    Dim s As String, r As Range

    With ActiveCell
        s = .Formula
        Set r = Range(s)
        s = r.Formula
        .Formula = s
    End With
End Sub
```

The macro will go to *Sheet2*, grab the formula in **M3** and put it back in *Sheet1*